# jQuery Conflict in struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2

In my Project I need to include pure JSP file to `Struts2` project. I tried to include my jsp into struts2 project. My JSP file already contains jquery.js. When I use this JSP into struts, the struts code is not working properly due to conflict of jquery.js.
Is there any way to use both jquery.js. I need to use both in my project.

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
```

**someJspfile.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="common/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="common/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="common/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
```

In someJspfile.jsp is not contain struts tag

Comment: post some code will help to figure out your problem.

Comment: **index.jsp**<br>`<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%> ........`<br> **somefile.jsp**<br>`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="common/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="common/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="common/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/css/jquery.dataTables.css">.........`<br>

Comment: add it in your question.

Comment: is your both jsp file are separate or you have include one in other ?

Comment: it separate only. i have solved my problem.thank you for your response.

Comment: @Visva If you solved the problem yo can post an answer and tell how did you do it.